# Passing managedObjectContext along to view/controller hierarchy

Tags: iphone, core-data, software-design

Managed object context in most cases created in application delegate.
What are the ways of passing it along to view/controller hierarchy, so every navigation/tab controller in the tree can have access to it. Passing it every time from parent to child may not be the best since I have to carry this information every time and sometimes not all of the controllers to the way of particular child may need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended design is to do a dependency injection.  This means that when you create a `UIViewController` you pass in the `NSManagedObjectContext` via a property.  If the `UIViewController` only needs a single or set of `NSManagedObject` instances then you would just hand those in via properties.

This design is more flexible and allows for greater reuse of your code.  Linking everything to a single "hard-coded" `NSManagedObjectContext` in the AppDelegate is fragile and reduces the flexibility of your code.

I discuss this in depth on [The Mac Developer Network](https://web.archive.org/web/20100622003356/http://www.mac-developer-network.com/articles/cd0004.html). (edit: lost link now via Wayback Machine's Cache)

Comment: The link to the article is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a main context object in your main Nib. And link the controllers with this object. Or create a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like) if you only use one MOC.

Comment: if controllers are in different nib rather than main then it will not work. Singleton is fair option.

Comment: A singleton is a broken design and should be avoided at all costs.